# Knockout binding: how to update value of an object stored in a observableArray()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, data-binding

I'm at the "hello world" stage with knockout.js and data-binding.

I can't find the right way to bind and update a member value of an object which is stored in an `observableArray`.

Binding works first time, but then it doesn't update itself in the webpage.

Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach:chains">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Obj id is <span data-bind="text: id"></span> </h3>
        <span data-bind="text: message"></span>         
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript part:

```
(function () {
  var Chain = function (chainId) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = chainId;
    self.message = "N/A";
    // etc. (more memberS)
};


var Model = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.chains = ko.observableArray();
};

 Model.prototype = {
    updateChains: function(updatedChains) {
         // here chain values are updated, in words:
         // if chain does not exist then create it and add it to self.chains
         // self.chains.push(newChain); 
         // otherwise update chain.message as:
         // existingChain.message = updatedMessage;
   }

var model = new Model();

$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(model);
});
}());
```

I debugged the code and everything is fine on the update part, the `message` gets a new value, but it's not visible in the UI (it remains "N/A"). It seems that i'm doing something wrong in the binding.

I tried several other ways but failed each time.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Knockout page on [Observable Arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html):

> **Key point: An `observableArray` tracks which objects are *in* the array, *not* the state of those objects**
>
> Simply putting an object into an `observableArray` doesn’t make all of that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an independent choice. An `observableArray` just tracks which objects it holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

If you want the `message` on a `Chain` to be observable:

```
var Chain = function (chainId) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = chainId;
    self.message = ko.observable("N/A");
    ...
};
```

Then, when you want to set the `message` on an existing `Chain` you need to do this:

```
existingChain.message(updatedMessage);
```

**Not** this:

```
existingChain.message = updatedMessage
```

Answer (score 1):

Observable arrays don't track their contents' state, only when the array itself is modified.

[Documentation (second paragraph)](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

One way to achieve your goal would be to have the members of your Chain class also be observable:

```
var Chain = function (chainId) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = chainId;
    self.message = ko.observable("N/A");
    // etc. (more members)
};
```

Your update function would then be setting the observable in the found object:

self.chains()[foundIndex].memberToUpdate(newValue)